# How to run a post -> failure element in a declarative pipeline in a Jenkinsfile conditionally only?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline for I'd like to define a global `post` -> `failure` element which is only executed on certain branches. It ought to be executed after all stages in order to capture any failue in the pipeline. I want to use imported methods (e.g. from other groovy scripts), i.e. instead of an `echo` command shown in the example.

My aim is to create a notification which only happens on a certain set of branches and only in case of failure of any stage in the pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        /* ... other stages ... */
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'whole pipeline successful'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'pipeline failed, at least one step failed'
        }
    }
}
```

[`post` is supposed to contain step](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post), just like `steps`, however steps are commands afaik (searched for one hours and didn't find a definition) and that means that I can't use `when` or nested steps (is that possible - I searched for hours as well).

I can't approach this with a linter, because all of them are limited to syntax checks and don't check the pipeline logic. I have tried the `/pipeline-model-converter/validate` URL which is painful because it can't be used from within the web sureface and in postman you need to approach OAuth authentification with trial and error. There's not even a Docker image for validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `script` block within the `post` block to execute Groovy statements. For example:

```
post {
    failure {
        script {
            if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'dev') {
                echo 'pipeline failed'
                // email...
            }
        }
    }
}
```